# How to attach debugger in Visual Studio 2022 to a Xamarin process running on a physical Android device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently working on an Android application that utilizes MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library). I've encountered an issue where my app is being terminated due to resource constraints. When the app restarts (triggered by an intent filter), I'd like to re-attach the debugger to continue the debugging process.

Is there a recommended approach to achieve this, ensuring a seamless debugging experience across app restarts?

[Process types to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK0rb.png)

I tried to look for Xamarin documentation, and how to attach to Android device process, but the solutions are for older versions of VS.

Comment: Did you try to use the VS -> Debug-> Attach to Process?